# Responsive way to get a div fill up its parent

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs contained in a wrapper, which size is relative to the height of the body. One of the divs has a fixed height, the other one is supposed to fill up the wrapper div and let the overflown content scroll (only the inner div).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HvC7K/

Usually I calculate the height of "#contactlist" via jQuery, but this time I need the page to be responsive. When I resize the browser window "#contactlist" is stuck at its defined height.
Do I have to recalculate the height everytime the body size changes or is there a way to get it done in CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is that it appears you want the container(#wrapper) to have a fixed height (per your example) but want the content to change sizes accord to the browser size?

Comment: What's flexible is the size of #wrapper. Its height is 80% of the body (I couldn't recreate that in jsfiddle). When I resize the browser now, the height of #wrapper also changes and therefor #contactlist should also shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I think you want to use some absolute positioning.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kPeyB/)

You could also set `overflow: auto;` and the scrollbars won't show unless necessary.

Comment: Updated, fixed to be 80% of jsFiddle IFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery solution with

`#contactlist` **CSS** height adjustment:

```
#wrapper { width: 200px; height: 400px; border: 4px solid black; }
#header { height: 50px; border: 2px solid red; }
#contactlist { overflow: scroll; height: 344px; border: 2px solid blue; }
```

(only modified the height of contact list)

**jQuery** code (replaced your one):

```
h = $('#wrapper').height() ;

windowh = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){

  var newh = h + ($(this).height() - windowh);
  $('#wrapper').height(newh);
  $("#contactlist").height(newh-56); //56 = 50 for header + 6 for border

});
```

With this code, simultaneous with window resize, you can increase or decrease height of both `#wrapper` and `#contactlist` with scroll.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ajp9h/

Comment: Also in only CSS way, you can obtain this by using height unit in '%' instead of 'px', have to use both wrapper and contactlist height in percentage, may adjust their height % for best fit then try window resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper { width: 200px;border: 4px solid black; }
#header { height: 50px; border: 2px solid red; }
#contactlist { overflow: visible; border: 2px solid blue; }
```

Remove wrapper height and use `overflow:visible;`

I am not sure if this is what you want

Jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/gDgvz/)

Comment: No sorry, the wrapper height is relative to the body height. #contactlist should scroll.

Comment: Sorry, question was not clear. Erik gave the right answer I guess